# Knockout many to many template issue

Tags: knockout.js

I have a site listing Speakers and Programs.
Each Speaker can have many Programs and each Program can have may Speakers.

In my Knockout implementation when the view changes, for some reason the related list just keeps growing instead of refreshing.

Does anyone know why this might happen?
http://jsfiddle.net/mawiseman/7fgXB/

Here is the JSON data returned from my server:

`var speaker = { Type: "Speaker", Data: { FirstName: "Speaker", LastName: "One", Programs: [] }};
var program = { Type: "Program", Data: { Name: "Program 1", Speakers: [] } };`

Comment: you shouldn't call **applyBindings** on the same view more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** call `ko.applyBindings` twice or more often. I refactored [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/V6vPY/1/) a little bit. Especially the binding / viewmodel.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   viewModel = new ItemViewModel(); 
   UpdateView("Speaker");
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

`ko.applyBindings` will be called only **once**. If you look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6vPY/1/) you will see that there is no selection of the right *speaker* or *program* I only used these example object.

Comment: Thanks. multiple bindings definitely was the issue.